# Passing in class names to react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass in a classname to a react component to change it's style and cannot seem to get working:

```
class Pill extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <button className="pill {this.props.styleName}">{this.props.children}</button>
    );
  }

}

<Pill styleName="skill">Business</Pill>
```

I am trying to change the style of the pill by passing in the name of the class that has the respective style. I am new to React so maybe I am not doing this the right way. Thanks

Answer (score 178, accepted):

In React, when you want to pass an interpreted expression, you have to open a pair of curly braces. Try:

```
render () {
  return (
    <button className={`pill ${ this.props.styleName }`}>
      {this.props.children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Using the [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) npm package

```
import classnames from 'classnames';

render() {
  return (
    <button className={classnames('pill', this.props.styleName)}>
      {this.props.children}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why is it better : performance ? readability ? others ? Literal strings (your first example) are part of ES6, so it's a standard. It make less code and avoid an import. It *feels* better for me, but the other solution may have arguments.

Comment: In the above example you're absolutely right, it is better to use ES6 strings. I would say classnames is better in terms of readability and DRY when you have to deal with conditionals, like in the classnames readme shows https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames#usage-with-reactjs.

Comment: {} Braces, [] Brackets, () Parentheses - you don't need to say "curly braces" because braces are curly by definition.

Comment: Important thing to note: if `props.styleName` is optional and you omit it you will have `undefined` in your `class` list. So ``{`pill ${ this.props.styleName }`}`` is not that nice. Also you will have redundant whitespace at the end.

Answer (score 45):

Just for the reference, for stateless components:

```
// ParentComponent.js
import React from 'react';
import { ChildComponent } from '../child/ChildComponent';

export const ParentComponent = () =>
  <div className="parent-component">
    <ChildComponent className="parent-component__child">
      ...
    </ChildComponent>
  </div>

// ChildComponent.js
import React from 'react';

export const ChildComponent = ({ className, children }) =>
  <div className={`some-css-className ${className}`}>
    {children}
  </div>
```

Will render:

```
<div class="parent-component">
  <div class="some-css-className parent-component__child">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't adding className prop to a React component pass on that className to the first container element instead of passing it as a name prop?

Comment: @theSereneRebel No, it doesn't. See an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-knuth-enyju

Comment: @theSereneRebel Whether that's a good thing or not is a different topic.

Answer (score 28):

`pill ${this.props.styleName}` will get "pill undefined" when you don't set the props

I prefer

```
className={ "pill " + ( this.props.styleName || "") }
```

or

```
className={ "pill " + ( this.props.styleName ? this.props.styleName : "") }
```

Comment: You will still have a redundant whitespace at the end. Not that it changes anything but still.

Comment: I stopped the empty white space like this: 
className={props.styleName ? "pill " + props.styleName : "pill" }

Answer (score 7):

For anyone interested, I ran into this same issue when using [css modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) and [react css modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules).

Most components have an associated css module style, and in this example my **Button** has its own css file, as does the **Promo** parent component. But I want to pass some additional styles to **Button** from **Promo**

So the `style`able Button looks like this:

**Button.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules'
import styles from './Button.css'

class Button extends Component {

  render() {

    let button = null,
        className = ''

    if(this.props.className !== undefined){
        className = this.props.className
    }

    button = (
      <button className={className} styleName='button'>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    )

    return (
        button
    );
  }
};

export default CSSModules(Button, styles, {allowMultiple: true} )
```

In the above Button component the **Button.css** styles handle the common button styles. In this example just a `.button` class

Then in my component where I want to use the **Button**, and I also want to modify things like the position of the button, I can set extra styles in `Promo.css` and pass through as the `className` prop. In this example again called `.button` class. I could have called it anything e.g. `promoButton`.

Of course with css modules this class will be `.Promo__button___2MVMD` whereas the button one will be something like `.Button__button___3972N`

**Promo.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CSSModules from 'react-css-modules';
import styles from './Promo.css';

import Button from './Button/Button'

class Promo extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
        <div styleName='promo' >
          <h1>Testing the button</h1>
          <Button className={styles.button} >
            <span>Hello button</span>
          </Button>
        </div>
      </Block>
    );
  }
};

export default CSSModules(Promo, styles, {allowMultiple: true} );
```

Comment: 2018 update: Using [propTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) and [defaultProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) to handle cases where a property may or may not exist is cleaner, and preferred.

Answer (score 7):

In Typescript you need to set types of `HTMLAttributes` and `React.FunctionComponent`.

In most cases you will need will be extending it to another interface or type.

```
const List: React.FunctionComponent<ListProps &
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={props.className}>
      <img className="mr-3" src={props.icon} alt="" />
      {props.context}
    </div>
  );
};

interface ListProps {
  context: string;
  icon: string;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As other have stated, use an interpreted expression with curly braces.

But do not forget to set a default.
Others has suggested using a OR statement to set a empty string if `undefined`.

But it would be even better to declare your Props.

**Full example:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Pill extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <button className={`pill ${ this.props.className }`}>{this.props.children}</button>
    );
  }

}

Pill.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
};

Pill.defaultProps = {
  className: '',
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by "interpolating" the className passed from the parent component to the child component using `this.props.className`. Example below:

```
export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <ChildComponent className="your-modifier-class" />
  }
}

export default class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <div className={"original-class " + this.props.className}></div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With React 16.6.3 and @Material UI 3.5.1, I am using arrays in className like `className={[classes.tableCell, classes.capitalize]}`

Try something like the following in your case.

```
class Pill extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <button className={['pill', this.props.styleName]}>{this.props.children}</button>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With React's support for string interpolation, you could do the following:

```
class Pill extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (
          <button className={`pill ${this.props.styleName}`}>{this.props.children}</button>
       );
    }
}
```