# How can I use Css Modules to concatenate a class with a variable

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

How could I convert this className:

`` className={`Tooltip__message Tooltip__message--${position}`} ``

to a css Module className?

There are two classes, and one concatenates a variable.

Comment: Can you add more details with an example.
IN your .module.css files what are the classNames?
and what possible values does your position hold?

Comment: I'm doing a tooltip React component with a prop you can choose a position, I made with scss and works but when I try to use modules, I can't find the way to convert that className. This is the variable:   position?: "top" | "left" | "right" | "bottom"

Answer (score 1):

You can either do this, normal JavaScript:

```
className={'wrapper searchDiv ' + this.state.something}
```

or the string template version, with backticks:

```es6
className={`wrapper searchDiv ${this.state.something}`}
```

Both types are of course just JavaScript, but the first pattern is the traditional kind.

Anyway, in JSX, anything enclosed in curly brackets is executed as JavaScript, so you can basically do whatever you want there. But combining JSX strings *and* curly brackets is a no-go for attributes.

Ref to https://stackoverflow.com/a/36209517/10789574

Comment: Sorry I refer to use CssModules: https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/