# How to use template literals in tailwindcss to change classes dynamically?

Tags: css, reactjs, templates, next.js, tailwind-css

I tried to change it with this line of code it but it doesn't work

```
const [click, setClick] = useState(false);

const closeNav = () => {
  setClick(!click);
};

const openNav = () => {
  setClick(!click);
};

<div
  className=" absolute inset-0 ${click ? translate-x-0 : -translate-x-full } 
        transform  z-400 h-screen w-1/4 bg-blue-300 "
>
  <XIcon onClick={closeNav} className=" absolute h-8 w-8 right-0 " />
</div>;
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<div className={`absolute inset-0 ${click ? 'translate-x-0' : '-translate-x-full'} transform z-400 h-screen w-1/4 bg-blue-300`}></div>

// Alternatively (without template literals):
<div className={'absolute inset-0 ' + (click ? 'translate-x-0' : '-translate-x-full') + ' transform z-400 h-screen w-1/4 bg-blue-300'}></div>
```

---

Just keep in mind not to use string concatenation to create class names, like this:

```
<div className={`text-${error ? 'red' : 'green'}-600`}></div>
```

Instead you can **select *complete*** class name:

```
<div className={`${error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600'}`}></div>

// following is also valid if you don't need to concat the classnames
<div className={error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600'}></div>
```

As long as a class name appears in your template *in its entirety*, Tailwind will not remove it from production build.

---

There are some more options available for you like using a library like [classnames](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) or [clsx](https://github.com/lukeed/clsx), or maybe Tailwind specific solutions like [twin.macro](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/twin.macro), [twind](https://github.com/tw-in-js/twind), [xwind](https://github.com/Arthie/xwind).

Further Reading:

- [React.js conditionally applying class names](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30533171/11613622)
- [How to dynamically add a class to manual class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36209517/11613622)
- [Correct way to handle conditional styling in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35762586/11613622)
- [Embedding Expressions in JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)
- [Template literals - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Optimizing for Production - Writing purgeable HTML - Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#writing-purgeable-html)

Comment: I was puzzled by the bug which was caused by template literal concatanations, thank you! Didn't know it was also warned against in docs: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth

Comment: You can safelist classes if you need to interpolate/concatenate template literals. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth

Comment: thank you so much, I was adding class names from props like `bg-${props.color}`  and couldn't get the desired result. Above answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const bgClass: any = {
gray: " bg-gray-300",
red: " bg-red-300",
orange: " bg-orange-300",
yellow: " bg-yellow-300",
green: " bg-green-300",
teal: " bg-teal-300",
blue: " bg-blue-300",
indigo: " bg-indigo-300",
purple: " bg-purple-300",
pink: " bg-pink-300 ",
```

}

```
const convertLabelToBg = (label: string, baseClass: string): string => {
    let className: string = baseClass;
    if (label) {
        className += bgClass[label];
    }
    return className;
}
```

It worked for me.
I have followed the documentation.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names