# Colors fetched from json don't work in Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, fetch, tailwind-css

I'm working on a React project that fetches data from a server and displays it. The colors are kept in the json, so I tried to set them with tailwind:

```
...
const bgcolor = `bg-[${card.color}]`
const textcolor = `text-[${card.color}]`

return (
    <div key={card.id} className={`w-[300px] ${bgcolor} bg-opacity-30 rounded-lg shadow py-6 px-6 text-white inline-block`}>
        <p className='text-lg font-bold'>{card.subject}</p>
        <p className='text-md font-semibold'>{card.task_name}</p>
        <p>{formattedDate}</p>
        <p>{formattedTime}</p>
        <p className={`${textcolor}`}>{card.task_info_link}</p>
        <p className={`${textcolor}`}>{card.task_submission_link}</p>
        <p className={`${textcolor}`}>{card.task_enrollment_link}</p>
    </div>
        )
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Here's an example of the json:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "subject": "subject",
        "task_name": "task_name",
        "color": "#F64D4D",
        "deadline": "2023-09-25T15:30:00.000Z",
        "task_info_link": "https://...",
        "task_submission_link": "https://...",
        "task_enrollment_link": "https://..."
    },
```

The interesting thing about it is that `#F64D4D` the only color (I've also in json: `#F6D14D`, `#CA4DF6`; but none of them seem to work) that appears BUT only in textcolor (the bg-color doesn't)

Comment: `className` is for classes; use `style` to set styles directly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically build classnames in TailwindCss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69687530/dynamically-build-classnames-in-tailwindcss)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use template literals in tailwindcss to change classes dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68020378/how-to-use-template-literals-in-tailwindcss-to-change-classes-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a class like `text-#F64D4D`, those classes don't exist, as you can see in the list of [Tailwind Text Color classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/text-color).

You could set it as a style yourself:

```
<p style={{ backgroundColor: card.color, color: card.color }}>{card.task_info_link}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Tailwind can't do this. I've managed to achieve the same result using style property:

```
<div key={card.id} style={{backgroundColor: `${card.color}30`, backgroundColorOpacity: 30}} className={`w-[300px] bg-opacity-30 rounded-lg shadow py-6 px-6 text-white inline-block`}>
    ...
    <p style={{color: `${card.color}`}}className="">{card.task_info_link}</p>
    <p style={{color: `${card.color}`}}className="">{card.task_submission_link}</p>
    <p style={{color: `${card.color}`}}className="">{card.task_enrollment_link}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I suggested in my answer, why would you post the same rather then accepting mine?