# How to add javascript variable within className - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, var

I'm struggling to understand how I can pass through JS variable into className like:

```
<img className="pos-1 speed-${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1}" src={Onion1} />
```

where `{Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1}` will set a range number so that I can add classes randomly for speed-1 speed-2 etc.

```
console.log(`pos-1 speed-${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1}.`);

<img className=`pos-1 speed-${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1}.` src={Onion1} />
```

Can anyone help?

Also tried:

```
const classes = () => {
    return `pos-${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1} speed-${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1}.`;
}

<img className={classes} src={Onion1} />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically add a class to manual class names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209432/how-to-dynamically-add-a-class-to-manual-class-names)

Answer (score 8):

Your last attempt is very close, you just forgot to enclose it in `{...}`:

```
className={`pos-1 speed-${Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1}`}
```

Any values passed as attributes/props in React that are not simple string literals need to be enclosed in `{...}`.