# How to override className on extended component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to position this component differently on a certain page. But when I provide it with another className property it is only using the original class's styling that was provided when declaring the component.

Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './label.css';

class Label extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.labelClass} />
    );
  }
}

export default Label;
```

Page where I want to position it differently:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './page.css';
import Label from '../common/label.jsx';

class Page extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Label className={styles.positionLeft} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Page;
```

**Normally I would do this with custom styling but I have to use media
   queries so this isn't possible in this situation.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by adding another optional property customClass to the component.

**Label**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './label.css';

class Label extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.labelClass + ' ' + this.props.customClass} />
    );
  }
}

export default Label;
```

**Page**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './page.css';
import Label from '../common/label.jsx';

class Page extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <Label customClass={styles.positionLeft} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `<Label>` is a custom component, you can to manually pass the `className` prop down.

This is a good use case for **[default props](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops)!**

```
class Label extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={this.props.className} />
    );
  }
}

Label.defaultProps = {
  className: styles.labelClass
}
```

That way, if no `className` is provided to `Label`, it will use the `labelClass` style, otherwise, it will use the prop.

Comment: Or use [classnames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521797/how-to-add-multiple-classes-to-a-reactjs-component) to apply more than one class.

Comment: That would be a possibility, the post made it sound more like a replacement than concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly reference the `className` property from `Label`'s props - try:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styles from './label.css';

class Label extends Component {
  render() {

    let { className } = this.props

    if (!className) {
      className = styles.labelClass
    }

    return (
      <div className={className} />
    );
  }
}

export default Label;
```

Comment: Valid answer, but you've basically created a manual implementation of defaultProps.

Comment: I saw your answer after I'd finished writing mine - indeed I have! You learn something new every day I guess... \*goes away to refactor codebase\*

Comment: Haha I know right... it's amazing how much out there is underutilized and unknown. I remember when I wrote my own equivalent of `Promise.all` 