# React using external css along with bootsrap framework classes

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Sorry if the heading doesn't seem accurate.

I am doing changes in my webpack to use external css in my component/container.

I am also using Bootstrap where we have inbuilt classes.

Now, I want to use external classes along with bootstrap classes on an element.

For example consider this, we are importing our external css like this

```
import Classes from './signup.css'
```

Since we are also using boostrap hence my button element would be something like this

```
<button type="submit" className="btn mx-auto btn-primary" onClick={this.submitHandler}>Submit</button>
```

By making changes in webpack, we can use CSS like this

```
className={Classes.something}
```

now I want to use this CSS along with my bootstrap classes and since an element can't have two class name, I am kind perplexed about how to proceed.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why not? https://stackoverflow.com/q/34521797/863110

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing something like this?

```
className={`class1 ${Classes.something}`}
```

This is also mentioned here in this stack question:
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521797/how-to-add-multiple-classes-to-a-reactjs-component)