# ReactJS advanced custom styling

Tags: css, reactjs

Using reactjs only, is it possible to do advanced styling similar to

```
#primary-nav .list-group-item.active {}
// or
#secondary-nav .list-group-item:hover>.background-item {}
```

in the first example I could do some rather simple javascript logic to figure out if the component is "active" but on the second example it's just so much simpler with css.

Is there a clear react+js solution for these situations that comes close to the simplicity of css?

Comment: Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521797/how-to-add-multiple-classes-to-a-reactjs-component)

Comment: Are you looking for CSS in JS? Try styled-components: https://www.styled-components.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`className` is applied exactly like a regular HTML `class`. So to correctly target `.background-image` like in

```
.list-group-item:hover>.background-item
```

Your `jsx` structure should look like

```
import './index.css'

const Component = () =>{
    return(
        <div className='list-group-item'>
            <div className='background-item' />
            <span>
                <div className='background-item' /> /*Targeting nested items '>' */
            </span>
         </div>
     )
}
```

You can use `jss` and [clsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clsx) to have dynamic and conditional styles. Here is an example using [MUI styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/styles)(`hooks` API), but you can use [styled components](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.25), [react-jss](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.25) or implement you're own style's solution based on [jss](https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.25).

```
   import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles'
   import clsx from 'clsx'

   const styles = {
       root:{
           color: 'white',
           '&:active':{
                color: 'red'
            }
       },

       hidden:{
           opacity: 0
       }
   }

   const useStyles = makeStyles(styles)

   const Component = ({ open }) =>{
       const classes = useStyles()

       const rootStyle = clsx({
           [classes.root] : true,
           [classes.hidden] : !open
       })

       return <div classsName={rootStyle} />
   }
```

`jss` also have lots of cool features like `theming` support, `styles interpolation` (a personal favorite), nested selectors, style's rules,etc. Definitely worth taking a look.

> Notice that `clsx` doesn't require `jss` to work, it's just a helper to conditionally apply classes. You can use it like `clsx({'foo' : true, 'bar': false})`

Comment: I'm trying to add all the css to the component as well. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, giving it a few days in hopes that you'll get some upvotes ( ;

Comment: Glad to hear. Definitely take a look on `styles interpolation`, it plays really well with react