# Update className style dynmically based on state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using React Hooks in my project and need trying to work out how to dynamically add a class to a `className` if the value of the state changes. I am using `react-hook-form` for validating my form.

**RegisterForm.jsx**

```js
<input
  className={styles.authoriseInput}
  placeholder="Email"
  name="email"
  ref={register({required: true, minLength: 4})}  # supposed to be a regex, but too long for this question
/>
{errors.email &&
  <p className={styles.errors}>Please enter a valid email.</p>
}
```

The second part works correctly and when there is an err, the `<p>` tag is shown. But I am stuck on how to update the `input`'s `className` property in the same sort of manner. I want to add a style to `authoriseInput` that sets the `border-color` when `error.email` is triggered.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a conditional to the clasName prop

```
<input
   className={errors.email ? styles.errorInput : styles.authoriseInput}
   placeholder="Email"
   name="email"
   ref={register({required: true, minLength: 4})}  # supposed to be a regex, but too 
   long for this question
/>
{errors.email &&
    <p className={styles.errors}>Please enter a valid email.</p>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally set `classNames` in the same way you would render component parts.

```
<input
  className={errors.email && styles.authoriseInput}
  placeholder="Email"
  name="email"
  ref={register({required: true, minLength: 4})}  # supposed to be a regex, but too long for this question
/>
{errors.email &&
  <p className={styles.errors}>Please enter a valid email.</p>
}
```

Comment: This will just result in undefined if error.email is false

Comment: I agree, it depends on your expected result. If you want to achieve a class addition I always prefer `className={[styles.authoriseInput, errors.email && styles.errorInput]}` as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40824714/13745258. On this way, you inherit the base input style and only extend by error styles

Comment: So the expected result is that the input will maintain its current styling, but will get a red border around it (imagine an invalid input on any website for login). What @sebastian suggested ends up with an error as it is always false, and what you mentioned above didn't style the input at all. I will keep playing around.

Comment: @intRG that's odd. What is the value of `styles.authoriseInput`. Are you eventually mixing up the use of  `Stylesheet` and `ClassNames`?

Comment: @sebastian I updated the question for clarification

Comment: WHOOPS THIS IS MY FAULT I SEE IT. I have border set to None in the error, I assume once that is removed it will work fine. Thanks!