# Some solution to chain styles in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-css-modules

In react using *css-modules* i'm assigning classes to components like this

```
import styles from './styles.module.css'

const SomeComponent = () => (
  <ChildComponent className={styles.SomeClass + ' ' + styles.AnotherClass} />
)
```

or i can assign like this

```
<ChildComponent className={`${styles.SomeClass} ${styles.AnotherClass}` />
```

Would you suggest the way how to transform **styles** variable, that we could assign classes like this

```
<ChildComponent className={styles.SomeClass.AnotherClass.OneMoreClass />
```

And of course we could use one class or two or as much as possible

Comment: Plenty of discussion here: [How to add multiple classes to a ReactJS Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521797/how-to-add-multiple-classes-to-a-reactjs-component)

Comment: @plichard, cool! I scrolled half of these discussions - nothing like styles.SomeClass.AnotherClass.OneMoreClass, should i scroll further? Any chances?

Comment: You would need to define a custom class that mapped the properties of the `styles` object to accommodate chaining. Here is a quick example [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/chained-properties-from-object-iuxrj), but I can't vouch for it as a solution.

Comment: @pilchard, it is. Thank you. Some changes required because one style can be used in component for different components so for each property we need a distinct such object and then chaining can be started. Otherwise this is solution. And _end is not needed, better replace it with toString()

Comment: Yes, of course, `toString()` is a more elegant solution, edited the sandbox. Glad it helped.