# Appending a class with Click messes up the whole css

Tags: css, reactjs, react-css-modules

I don't really know why transforming the X position while appending an additional class to make the slide effect isn't working as expected in React, as it does while using vanilla javascript.
This is the code example

```
.inputModal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: rgba(25, 26, 26, 0.74);
  left: -8px;
  top: 30%;
  box-shadow: 10px 15px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translateX(-93%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
} 

.InputModal.show {
transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

And the simple Component which should append the class show on button click

```
function InputModal() {
  const [toggleBtn, setToggleBtn] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className={toggleBtn ? "inputModal" : "InputModal show"}>
      <Input />
      <div
        className="toggleBtn"
        onClick={() => {
          setToggleBtn(!toggleBtn);
        }}
      >
        <i className="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Once I click the toggle button(div) the show class is appended on to the div, but the div is losing all the previous set stylings and gets messed up

Comment: You are not appending the class you are changing it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add multiple classes to a ReactJS Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521797/how-to-add-multiple-classes-to-a-reactjs-component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append instead of change the classes, just like:

```
function InputModal() {
  const [toggleBtn, setToggleBtn] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div className={`inputModal ${toggleBtn ? "" : "InputModal show"}`}>
      <Input />
      <div
        className="toggleBtn"
        onClick={() => {
          setToggleBtn(!toggleBtn);
        }}
      >
        <i className="fas fa-align-justify"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: However, this is far from the best practices using react IMHO

Comment: what would be the best approach?

Comment: You could use the state to decide if you component should render or not. If you do that, it will only be at the DOM if needed

Comment: Oh, I just realized what you want, in this case I don't think there is just another way to do it. Made a sandbox, take a look: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-paper-rmrm5?file=/src/App.js:115-124