# How to pass props to react component to change text color

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-props

I have a react component that has an `h3` with dark gray text color.  I would like to reuse the component in a place where the background color is also dark gray, so I need to change the `h3` text color to something lighter.

This is how the component was before I needed to change the text color in some areas:

```
// other imports
import styles from "./styles/subheader.module.css"

export default function Subheader(props) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h3 className={styles.h3}>{props.text}</h3>
      <div className={styles.headerUnderline}></div>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

CSS:

```
.h3 {
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(33, 37, 41);
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.headerUnderline {
  width: 100px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: rgb(219, 190, 157);
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

I tried this which didn't work:

```
<Subheader text="PRODUCTS" style={{color: "rgb(219, 190, 157)"}} />
```

So I tried passing props and changed my component:

```
//other imports
import styles from "./styles/subheader.module.css"

export default function Subheader(props) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h3 className={styles.h3 + " " + props.lightText ? styles.lightText : styles.darkText}>{props.text}</h3>
      <div className={styles.headerUnderline}></div>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

And changed CSS:

```
.h3 {
  font-family: var(--font-family);
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}
.lightText {
  color: rgb(219, 190, 157);
}
.darkText {
  color: rgb(33, 37, 41);
}
```

And used like:

```
// both render light text with no .h3 styling like centered text
<Subheader text="WE DELIVER" lightText={true} />
<Subheader text="PRODUCTS" lightText={false} />
```

But that didn't work either.

Comment: You're missing a closing " on your style tag

Comment: Thanks, I corrected that, it was a typo in copy and pasting to ask the question.  Trying to inline style there still doesn't work.

Comment: How are you importing your css to react? you either need to include it as a var or const in the function and use it or include you css file with(example): import styles from './my-style.module.css';  <- something like this... have you done it? if you use that line for example then the code from your first try should work... because of the use of styles... just change the filename to what you need fit.

Comment: @Shlomtzion I import it with 'import styles from "./styles/subheader.module.css"'.  I edited my post to show.  The CSS works just fine.  The h3 text color in the Subheader component is dark grey and that renders just fine.  What I'm trying to figure out is how to change the  Subheader text color to a light color when used with a dark backgound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you change your `h3` **className** to template string:

```
<h3 className={`${styles.h3} ${props.lightText ? styles.lightText : styles.darkText}`}>{props.text}</h3>
```

or at least last part of it:

```
<h3 className={styles.h3 + " " + `${props.lightText ? styles.lightText : styles.darkText}`}>{props.text}</h3>
```

Here you can find a lot of great examples how to add multiple classnames: [How to add multiple classes to a ReactJS Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521797/how-to-add-multiple-classes-to-a-reactjs-component)

Comment: Just a note the second part not being one template string is better as:

<h3 className={styles.h3 + ` ${props.lightText ? styles.lightText : styles.darkText}`}>{props.text}</h3>

Otherwise there will be a warning about "no-useless-concat".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `style` prop like you did here:

```js
<Subheader text="PRODUCTS" style={{color: "rgb(219, 190, 157)"}} />
```

But notice that you're not passing the `style` prop to an element, but to a component, so, like `text`, it can be accessed inside the component on the `props` object (i.e. `props.style`).

This how you can access `style`:

```js
export default function Subheader(props) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <h3 style={props.style} className={styles.h3}>{props.text}</h3>
      <div className={styles.headerUnderline}></div>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Live example: [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-glitter-shf7s?file=/src/App.js:278-497)