# Add new css class with out replace the olders on a React Component

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

I have 2 components:

```
ButtonComponent:

export function Button(props: ButtonProps) {
  return <button className={styles.assignButton} {...props} />;
}
```

and I want to use then like that:

```
In another component:

<Button type="submit" className={styles.btnSubmit}>
  Cadastre-se
</Button>
```

But wen I do this I'm lost the css class **styles.assignButton** defined on the first declaration of the component.

Has some way to do this with out lost that css class and keep the both? Some way like a spread operator, I don't now.

Grateful :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing in class names to react components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230635/passing-in-class-names-to-react-components)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in this way in you Button components:

```
<button className={`${styles.assignButton} ${props.className}`} />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
// Button.tsx

export function Button({ className, ...rest }: ButtonProps) {
  return <button className={`${styles.assignButton} ${className || ''}`} {...rest} />;
}
```

Do note that if you don't pass in a class name you'll have a trailing space after the assignButton style. Handling class names in various components can become quite unreadable so it's probably best to use [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) or something similar.

```
// Button.tsx

export function Button({ className, ...rest }: ButtonProps) {
  return <button className={classNames(styles.assignButton, className)} {...rest} />;
}
```